# Delphi VirtualKey to WideString

Tags: delphi, winapi, keyboard, delphi-7

I would like to convert a virtual key to a WideString.
That's what I have so far...

```
function VKeytoWideString (Key : Word) : WideString;
var
 WBuff         : array [0..255] of WideChar;
 KeyboardState : TKeyboardState;
 UResult       : Integer;
begin
 GetKeyBoardState (KeyboardState);
 UResult := ToUnicode(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), KeyboardState, WBuff, 0,0);
 Result  := WBuff;
 case UResult of
  0 : Result := '';
  1 : SetLength (Result, 1);
  2 :;
  else
   Result := '';
 end;
end;
```

it always returns 0 but why?
Please help.

Comment: The delphi part is my weakness so I'm just leaving this as a comment. As far as I know, as a C++ programmer, the VirtualKey's value is the same as the character's value.

Comment: For numerals 0-9 and letters A-Z, yes, @Ken. There are a lot more characters to type than just those, though. It has nothing to do with the programming language, either.

Comment: @RobKennedy Didn't wanna take a chance with leaving a bad answer. And if it doesn't have nothing to do with the language completely - I want to point to the OP that he should TranslateMessage and get it through WM_CHAR. that worked for my native language when I had the need

Comment: WM_CHAR is Ascii only I think.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are setting the `cchBuff` parameter of `ToUnicode()` to 0 instead of the actual buffer size, so the function cannot store any characters it translates.

Try this instead:

```
function VKeytoWideString (Key : Word) : WideString; 
var 
  WBuff         : array [0..255] of WideChar; 
  KeyboardState : TKeyboardState; 
  UResult       : Integer;
begin 
  Result := '';
  GetKeyBoardState (KeyboardState); 
  ZeroMemory(@WBuff[0], SizeOf(WBuff));
  UResult := ToUnicode(key, MapVirtualKey(key, 0), KeyboardState, WBuff, Length(WBuff), 0); 
  if UResult > 0 then
    SetString(Result, WBuff, UResult)
  else if UResult = -1 then
    Result := WBuff;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that cchBuff is the Length of the Buffer.

Comment: I just tested it on a chinese Windows and it gives me only ascii chars back like this: http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/9506/clipboard01l.png It converts it to Hanyu Pinyin. Any idea why? Oo